# Can not use Full-text search in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, full-text-search

I followed the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) and try to use "Full-text search" but it's not work and i got an error.

```
Unsupported lookup 'search' for CharField or join on the field not permitted
```

I use MySQL. It's work with Starts-with search,  Exact matches and Regex search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's an error in the documentation of DRF because the Django documentation clearly states that full-text search is supported only on PostgreSQL:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/search/#document-based-search
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#the-search-lookup

> To use the search lookup, 'django.contrib.postgres' must be in your INSTALLED_APPS.